# kivyMD how to call a function from builder?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm new on kivyMD someone can help with this problem please.

I have two files: one is the main python file and the other is the builder file.

I want to call a function called `show_data` from the builder file.

Someone know the proper way to call the function?

This is the main.py file

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from helpers import username_input,loginButton

class PrototypeChikis(MDApp):

    def build(self):

        screen = Screen()
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"

        self.username = Builder.load_string(username_input)
        self.button = Builder.load_string(loginButton)
        screen.add_widget(self.username)
        screen.add_widget(self.button)
        return screen

    def show_data(self,obj):
        print(self.username.text)

PrototypeChikis().run()
```

This is the kv. file

```
username_input = """
MDTextField:
    hint_text: "Enter username"
    icon_right: "tanker-truck"
    icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y': 0.5}
    size_hint_x:None
    width:300
    
"""

loginButton = """
MDRectangleFlatButton:
    text: 'Log In'
    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.4}
    on_press: self.show_data()   
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some function, you can copy and paste the code I have just modified it a little bit, I put everything in a single file:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
try:
    from helpers import username_input,loginButton
except:
    pass
username_input = """
MDTextField:
    id: texto_jbsidis
    hint_text: "Enter username"
    icon_right: "tanker-truck"
    icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y': 0.5}
    size_hint_x:None
    width:300
    on_text: app.show_while_typing(self.text)
    
"""

loginButton = """
MDRectangleFlatButton:
    text: 'Log In'
    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.4}
    on_press: app.show_data()   
"""

class PrototypeChikisjbsidis(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Screen()
    def build(self):

        
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"

        self.username = Builder.load_string(username_input)
        self.button = Builder.load_string(loginButton)
        self.screen.add_widget(self.username)
        self.screen.add_widget(self.button)
        return self.screen

    def show_while_typing(self,the_text_from_the_jbsidis_text_field):
        print(len(the_text_from_the_jbsidis_text_field),the_text_from_the_jbsidis_text_field)

    def show_data(self):
        """
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: 'Log In'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.4}
            on_press: app.show_data()   
        """
        t="self.screen.children[1] is MDTextField texto_jbsidis "
        Textfield_23=self.screen.children[1]
        the_jbsidis_text_is=Textfield_23.text
        print(the_jbsidis_text_is)

PrototypeChikisjbsidis().run()
```

The picture, jbsidis:

[image]